# Called to stored procedure through VB.net application not working

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have a VB.Net application that calls the database stored procedure and it supposedly suppose to look for tasks in a table with the Status of "Wait" and then updates it to executing and then generates the report.

However, I have ran the step in Visual Studio but it seems it doesn't to run the store procedure or run the stored procedure with no result .

I have individually ran the stored procedure through SQL Developer to check it and it works, so I don't think it's the problem.

I find that the `rsresult` never has rows so I am wondering do I need to add another line of code after `ExecuteReader`?

Can you all please help?

Below is the function and stored procedure

```
Public Function SelectGetTasktoExec(ByVal plngCount As Integer, ByVal 
pstrIPAddr As String, ByRef pdicResult As Dictionary) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Dim blnResult As Boolean
    Dim strCaller As String = ""
    Dim strErrMsg As String = ""
    Dim lngRet As Integer
    Dim rsResult As OracleDataReader = Nothing
    Dim dicItem As Dictionary
    Dim intIndex As Integer

    Try
        m_TranObj.CreateSPCaller("PKG_TD_BATCH_REPORT.SELECT_REPRINT_TASK")
        m_TranObj.AddSPParams("i_task_count", OracleDbType.Decimal, 10, plngCount, ParameterDirection.Input)
        m_TranObj.AddSPParams("i_ipaddr", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 16, pstrIPAddr, ParameterDirection.Input)
        m_TranObj.AddSPParams("ocs_name", OracleDbType.RefCursor, 20, Nothing, ParameterDirection.Output)
        m_TranObj.AddSPParams("o_err_code", OracleDbType.Decimal, 20, lngRet, ParameterDirection.Output)

        If Not m_TranObj.RunSPReturnRS(lngRet, "o_err_code", rsResult) Then
            strErrMsg = "call Pkg_Td_Batch_Report.SELECT_REPRINT_TASK failed."
            Throw New Exception()
        End If

        If lngRet <> 0 Then
            strErrMsg = "Call Pkg_Td_Batch_Report.SELECT_REPRINT_TASK failed,Error code:" & CStr(lngRet)
            Throw New Exception()
        End If

        intIndex = gc_DicFirstKey

        rsResult.Read()
        While rsResult.HasRows()
            dicItem = New Dictionary

            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_TASK_NO, rsResult("TASK_NO") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_QUEUE_NO, rsResult("QUEUE_NO") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_START_DATE, rsResult("START_DATE") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_END_DATE, rsResult("END_DATE") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_STORAGE_PATH, rsResult("STORAGE_PATH") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_DATA_SOURCE, rsResult("DATA_SOURCE") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_TEMPLATE_NAME, rsResult("TEMPLATE_NAME") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_SOFT_COPY_FORMATS, rsResult("SOFT_COPY_FORMATS") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_SCHEDULED_EXECUTE_DATE, rsResult("SCHEDULED_EXECUTE_DATE") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_HARD_DISTRIBUTION_IND, rsResult("PRINT_IND") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_SOFT_DISTRIBUTION_IND, rsResult("EXPORT_IND") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_RESULT_PATH, rsResult("RESULT_PATH") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_PRINTER_NAME, rsResult("PRINTER_NAME") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_TRACTOR_NO, rsResult("TRACTOR_NO") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_TEMPLATE_NO, rsResult("TEMPLATE_NO") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_DUPLEX_PRINT_IND, rsResult("DUPLEX_PRINT_IND") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_DESCRIPTION, rsResult("DESCRIPTION") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_DEPT_DIVISION_CODE, rsResult("DEPT_DIVISION_CODE") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_SYSDATE, Strings.Format(rsResult("SYSDATE"), gc_FormatDateTime) & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_FROM_PAGE, rsResult("FROM_PAGE") & "")
            dicItem.Add(gc_KEY_TO_PAGE, rsResult("TO_PAGE") & "")

            'add end
            pdicResult.Add(intIndex, dicItem)
            intIndex += 1

        End While
        SBL_Error.DebugLog(strCaller, "End")
        blnResult = True

    Catch excep As System.Exception
        blnResult = False
        SBL_Error.ErrorLog(strCaller, strErrMsg & excep.ToString)
        Throw excep
    Finally
        result = blnResult
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

Here is the RunSPReturnRS method:

```
Public Function RunSPReturnRS(ByRef plngCnt As Integer, ByVal pstrReturnName 
As String, ByRef prsResult As Object) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Dim blnResult As Boolean
    Dim strCaller As String = ""
    Dim strErrMsg As String = ""
    Dim strMsg As String = ""
    Dim rsresult As String = ""

    Try
        If Not mblnConnected Then
            If Not Connect() Then
                strErrMsg = "Can not open connection!"
            End If
        End If

        prsResult = mCmd.ExecuteReader()

        If prsResult.HasRows Then
            prsResult.Read()
            prsResult = prsResult(0).ToString()
            strMsg = "Batch Date is" + Space(1) + prsResult
        Else
            prsResult = prsResult
        End If

        If pstrReturnName Is "" Then
            plngCnt = mCmd.Parameters(pstrReturnName).Value
        End If

        mCmd.Dispose()
SBL_Error.DebugLog(strCaller, strMsg)
        blnResult = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        SBL_Error.ErrorLog(strCaller, ex.ToString())
        blnResult = False
    Finally
        result = blnResult
    End Try
    Return result
```

Comment: Use the correct tags - you appear to  be using oracle and **not** sql server

Comment: Sorry, thanks for for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

There's little to go on here... but... if the stored procedure only returns a single row then you'd never see the result.

You need the `rsResult.Read` within the While loop:

```
While rsResult.HasRows
    rsResult.Read
    '  do your processing...
End While
```

Comment: I did do that , but it seems that its not returning anything. I have ran the stored procedure and it does have output but dont' know why through the vb.net application, i don't get any returns.  The "HasRows" is always false